# Struggling to form a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I am working on a problem that involves creating an inventory of supermarket stock, and I'm having considerable difficulties. What the program is supposed to do is prompt a user for input (item name, quantity, weight, and price) and then add this item into a sorted (by increasing alphabetical order) database.

So my idea is to create a linked list. I've started by defining the following:

```
typedef struct item_t item;
struct item_t{
    char name;
    int weight;
    int price;
    int quantity;
    item *next;
};
```

So the idea that I'm going for is that every item has its details stored in this structure type, and that *next will point to the next structure in the linked list.

Next I came up with this:

```
void add_new_node_at_end(char *user_input){
    new_node = (*item_t)malloc(sizeof(item_t))
    if (new_node == NULL){
        printf("Memory failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Is this correct so far?

Now, I'm not too sure what to do about the pointer *next when I create a new node, nor do I know how to change the fields of the structure. Can I simply use `new_node.item = 'string'` or do I need to malloc the field names as well?

Sorry, this might be a silly question but I really need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: "nor do I know how to change the fields of the structure" - Until you know how to setup basic data in a  structure correctly, *and* how single-indirection pointers are used in the C language,  *and* basic dynamic memory management, you're going to run into wall-after-wall. You asked for direction so...: Learn those *first*.

Answer (score 0):

You need one global root pointer (`item_t* root`) and initialize it with `NULL` which is the start of your list. For a single-linked list, point the next pointer of the new element to the element pointed at by root, and change root to point to the newly created element.

By doing this, you create daisy-chain of elements. The end is reached when `item.next == NULL` .